# TCPv6: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies - nginx

Tags: cookies, nginx, tcp

I am using nginx with version 1.4.0. Getting error as : TCPv6: Possible SYN flooding on port 80. Sending cookies.

It is serving media traffic and whenever number of incoming connections crosses 7K. file size served is about 1.5Mb.
below are few details for reference :

part of nginx conf :

```
`worker_processes  auto;
 events {
 worker_connections  4096;
 use epoll;
 multi_accept on;
 }
 worker_rlimit_nofile   100001;

 http {
 include       mime.types;
 default_type  video/mp4;
 proxy_buffering           on;
 proxy_buffer_size         4096k;
 proxy_buffers             5 4096k;
 sendfile                  on;
 keepalive_timeout         30;
 tcp_nodelay               on;
 tcp_nopush               on;
 reset_timedout_connection on;
 gzip                      off;
 server_tokens          off;`
```

`

sysctl parameters are :

```
net.core.somaxconn=65535
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0 # purpsely set to 1 as NATed client were facing issue.
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 250000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.core.rmem_max = 134217728
net.core.wmem_max = 134217728
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 67108864
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 67108864
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 250000
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = htcp
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 4096 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10
```

server used : CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

## cat /proc/meminfo

MemTotal:       1588152040 kB

## lscpu

Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                60

Please assist how sync flood error can be solved.

Comment: Can someone please assist here .

Comment: This is a site about programming. I don't think anyone can help you here.